# Office.EventType.ItemChanged doesn't seem to fire

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to test a simple console.log print test when I move from one email to another in outlook. I am following the instructions from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane#handling-ui-updates-based-on-currently-selected-message

My manifest file already supports pinning and I use pinning in all my outlook addin projects.

I followed this code from microsoft yet it doesn't seem to do anything in the developer console:

```
function itemChanged(eventArgs) {
  // Update UI based on the new current item
  UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox.item);
}

// Example implementation
function UpdateTaskPaneUI(item)
{
  // Assuming that item is always a read item (instead of a compose item).
  if (item != null) console.log(item.subject);
}

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    // Set up ItemChanged event
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged);

    UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox.item);
  });
};
```

I was assuming that I was going to receive the subject of which ever email I was highlighted on in outlook but nothing happened. I also double clicked on an email to see if the event was fired only by the email being in its own window and nothing happened still.

I am running Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20254) 64-bit

Comment: Is your task pane pinned at the time when you select another item in Outlook?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - Yes it is.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - Weird, I think I figured it out. I was testing the code in the dev tools and it didn't work but when I ran it directly into the javascript file for the outlook addin it worked. I will write an answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work.
I was first testing in the dev tool's console so I assumed that would have worked but it was casuing me errors. The moment I tested the code in the javascript for the outlook addin itself it started to work:

```
Office.onReady((info) => {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    function itemChanged(eventArgs) {
      // Update UI based on the new current item
      UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox.item);
    }
    
    // Example implementation
    function UpdateTaskPaneUI(item)
    {
      // Assuming that item is always a read item (instead of a compose item).
      if (item != null) console.log(item.subject);
    }
  
        // Set up ItemChanged event
        Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged);
    
        UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox.item);
})
```