# Office.js - Office.EventType.ItemChanged loose focus after

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am using Office.js to develop a custom Outlook Add-In. A part of my script includes an event handler, to detect whenever a new e-mail has changed:

```js
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, selectedMailItemChanged);

async function selectedMailItemChanged(eventArgs){
    console.log("E-mail was selected for the first time, or the email selection has changed.");
}
```

The above code works fine. When I select a new e-mail, the `selectedMailItemChanged` function gets triggered, and writes to the console.

However, it stops working on specific instances, such as when I click on a link. In one of my pages, I have the below link:

```html
<a
:href="'edient:Command=ShowEditForm&LicenceCode=XXXXXX&ControllerID=JobShipment&BusinessEntityPK=' + shipment.fetch_id">
 <span>Open Shipment</span>
</a>
```

The above href links to an internal application. The link works fine, but after it is clicked, the `selectedMailItemChanged` function no longer fires when the selection changes.

Comment: Is your task pane pinned at the time when you select another item in Outlook?

Comment: Take a look at the similar post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557205/office-eventtype-itemchanged-doesnt-seem-to-fire

Comment: If you still have a problem with this event I'd suggest filing an issue on the `OfficeJS` repo. Don't forget to update the thread with a valid reference to the issue posted then.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes, the task pane is pinned when I try to select another item in Outlook. The similar post doesn't fix it at my end, unfortunately..

Comment: Post the issue to the [OfficeJS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo at github.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Posted here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3002